# How disable purple screen at boot time when it shows?

Tags: boot

I am on Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to keep the purple screen, THOUGH, sometimes I also would like to hit a shortcut at boot time so I can see what the OS is doing. Is there anyway to accomplish this? Or my only option is with/out purple screen altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit the `shift` key right after the BIOS screen, and, when presented with the boot line, remove `quiet splash` from its end. That done, you shouldn't see the splash screen, and the change is only valid for one boot.

Comment: it does not work. In Ubuntu 11.10 the presented boot line only blinks at the screen and does not allow me to type "quiet splash". Alterantives?

Comment: You have to press `e` to edit it, as stated at the bottom of the screen. When done editing, press `ctrl+x` to boot.